# how to get cards to show up in pygame as they are played and not have the screen freeze if clicked on?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to make a blackjack game in Pygame. I've got to the point where if I take a new card the cards start showing up. However, there are some issues:

1. The screen is blank until the first card is drawn at which point you see 3 cards. so you never see the first two on their own.
2. How would I go about making it so that it can be played and then followed by dealers cards showing as he plays(i have the dealers logic done already.
3. The GUI screen is always not responding when you click it, how to mitigate that.

The code:

```
from random import shuffle
import pygame

class card:

    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
        if type(self.rank) == int:
            self.value = rank
        elif self.rank == 'ACE':
            self.value = 11
        else:
            self.value = 10
    def showval(self):
        print('{} of {}'.format(self.rank, self.suit))
        print('card value is: ', self.value)

class deck:

    def __init__(self):
        ranks = [i for i in range(2, 11)] + ['JACK', 'QUEEN', 'KING',
        'ACE']
        suits = ['SPADE', 'HEART', 'DIAMOND', 'CLUB'] 

        self.cards = []
        for i in suits:
            for j in ranks:
                self.cards.append(card(i,j))
        self.shuffle()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.cards)
    def shuffle(self):
        shuffle(self.cards)


class hand:

    def __init__(self,name=None):

        self.contents = []
        self.deal(2,theDeck)
        self.show()
    def deal(self,x,theDeck):
        if len(theDeck) < x:
            theDeck = deck()
        for j in range (x):
            self.contents.append(theDeck.cards.pop(0))
            self.total = sum(i.value for i in self.contents)
    def show(self):
        print('your cards are:')
        for i in self.contents:
            print(i.rank,'of',i.suit)

    def makedecision(self):
        hitorstand = ''
        while hitorstand not in ('h' , 'H' , 's' , 'S'):
            self.show()
            hitorstand = input('enter "H" to hit or "S" to stand: ')
        return hitorstand


    def play(self):
        decision = self.makedecision()
        if decision in('h', 'H') :
            self.deal(1,theDeck) 
        elif decision in ('s', 'S'):
            print('ok you have chosen to stand.')
            self.show()
### end of classes
theDeck = deck()

pygame.init()
cardpngs={'CLUB':{'ACE':pygame.image.load('pcp\\CLUb
\\1.png'),2:pygame.image.load('pcp\\CLUB
\\2.png'),3:pygame.image.load('pcp\\CLUB
\\3.png'),4:pygame.image.load('pcp\\CLUB},'HEART':  
{'ACE':pygame.image.load('pcp\\HEART\\1.png').............}}

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0, 0 ,0)
white =(255,255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
back_ground = pygame.image.load('tablesmall.png')
myhand=hand()

def start_game():
    gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('BlackJack')
    gameDisplay.blit(back_ground,(1,1))
    gameExit = False
    while not gameExit: 
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
               if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                exit()
                gameExit=True
        card_xy = 1

        myhand.play()
        for i in myhand.contents:
            gameDisplay.blit((cardpngs[i.suit][i.rank]),
            (card_xy,card_xy))
            card_xy+=30
        pygame.display.update()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_game()
```

The escape button doesn't seem to work to exit as the  (if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE) would suggest. the plan is to also add some buttons to facilitate laying the game.

Answer (score 0):

You asked 3 separate questions, unrelated each other. Each one should be a post on stack overflow.
I'm going to answer the first one, which is simpler to solve, and make only a couple of comments on the other to try to point what I think is the right way to go.

---

> The screen is blank until the first card is drawn at which point you see 3 cards. so you never see the first two on their own. I'm going to answer the first which is more simple, and make only few comments on the others.

This is because when you call `myhand=hand()` you give the first two cards to the player. Then in the main loop you call `myhand.play()` which asks the user to hit a card or stay. You blit the cards on the screen and call `pygame.display.update()` for the first time **after** the player choice, so if the player chooses to hit, 3 cards are blit. The easiest solution is to move the call to `myhand.play()` *after* the call to `pygame.display.update()`. So first the cards are blit, and then the player can make a choice.

---

> How would I go about making it so that it can be played and then followed by dealers cards showing as he plays.

You can consider the dealer as another player. Make a new class `Dealer`, which inherits from `hand`, and override the `makedecision` method. Instead of asking the player, put here the dealer choice.
Of course you also need to replicate this portion of code:

```
card_xy = 1
for i in myhand.contents:
    gameDisplay.blit((cardpngs[i.suit][i.rank]),(card_xy,card_xy))
    card_xy+=30
```

for the dealer to blit the delaer's cards, at a different place on the screen.

> The GUI screen is always not responding when you click it, how to mitigate that.

This is really to broad to answer here, since your code does not show any attempt on this aspect.
The general answer is that you need to catch the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` and / or `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` events in the event loop, obtaining the mouse position (to identify for example the card clicked by the user) and associate a proper action.